# How to select an UIImage from gallery and set first selected image as root image in objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to select an UIImage from gallery and set first selected image as root image and then perform different operations to the other UIImages. How can I implement this ?

Please suggest me according changes in my code

My code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   //_backImage.image =chosenImage;  _backImage is the root image

   [mainImagesArray addObject:_centreImage.image];
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: iosLearner check my answer.It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

First you need to pick the image from Gallery

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
   [arrayImage addObject:image];
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Then For root Image

```
i = 0;
for (UIImage *img in arrayImage)
{
  if(i=0){
     cameraGalleryImage.image = img  //set the root image here as you first select the image as root so always it will be in 0th index.
  }
  else
  {
       ............ //do the operation for other images 
  }
}
i++;
```